# How to customize the payload section of the JWT response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

What do I need to do to customize the `url(r'^auth/login/', obtain_jwt_token)` view to allow me to add data to the JWT token

I have a django-rest-framework API that is used by independent web applications. What I want is to return to the web app the logged in user's role and permissions together with what djangorestframework-jwt already returns.

I already have the roles in a python dictionary but I can't figure out what is required to override the default payload.

user_payload = {'user': user, 'roles': roles}

I thought it was as simple as replacing the 'user' in `payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)` with my user_payload but then am getting serializer errors. Is there a cleaner/easier way to do it?

djangorestframework==3.4.7, djangorestframework-jwt==1.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER**
Responsible for controlling the response data returned after login or refresh. Override to return a custom response such as including the serialized representation of the User.

Defaults to return the JWT token.

Example:

```
def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    return {
        'token': token,
        'user': UserSerializer(user).data
    }
```

Default is `{'token': token}`

Comment: This is good and works. However, how would I be able to add "content" to the token itself? I want to be able "manipulate" the private section of the token so that when the web app send me the token later, I get information from the token instead of going to fetch it from the database afresh..

Comment: I think `JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` setting works for this case. According to docs it says you can `Specify a custom function to generate the token payload`.